# Retrieve values from database to array in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Someone please help me..

I have a database with tables like this..

[image: myDB]

Which the column under pcNAME could have multiple values.  now I wanted to retrieve the values of "update_Patient" and "update_Medinfo" into an array, that shall be updated later with a new value.. oh by the way, the values under "update_Patient" and "update_Medinfo" are not always a "no", it can hold "ID1,ID2,ID3", so I wanted to just update this, the way that if this is the case, It'll just add the new ID together with the other IDS.

I tried using the following codes, but  the values under "update_Patient" and "update_Medinfo" did not update. please help me..

```
$get = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT *, COUNT(id) as count FROM `pcnames`");
        while($roww = mysqli_fetch_array($get))
        {
        $allpp[$roww["update_Patient"]] = $roww ;
        $allminfo[$roww["update_Medinfo"]] = $roww ;
        $pcID[$roww["id"]] = $roww;
        $count = $roww["count"];
        }

        for($idx = 0; $idx <= $count; $idx++)
        {
            if ($allpp[$idx] == "no")
            { 
                $allpp[$idx] = "";
            }
            if ($allminfo[$idx] == "no")
            {
                $allminfo[$idx] = "";
            }
            $allpp[$idx] = $allpp[$idx]",web-id"$z;
            $allminfo[$idx]= $allminfo[$idx]",web-id"$y; 
            $update = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE `pcnames` SET `update_Patient` = '$allpp[$idx]' , `update_Medinfo` = '$allminfo[$idx]' WHERE `id` = '$pcID[$idx]' ");
```

The variables $z and $y, is just numbers that are incremented whenever there is new ID to be added.
Thank you in advance! any help would be much appreciated!

Everytime a new id is created, i wanted to add it to the list of ids under "update_Patient" and "update_Medinfo". so for example,

```
  pcName   |       update_Patient     |    upadte_Medinfo 
   PC1     | web-id1,web-id2,web-id3  | web-id1,web-id2,web-id3
   PC2     | web-id1,web-id2,web-id3  | web-id1,web-id2,web-id3
```

if new Id has been added,ex. web-id4, the list of ids will be updated, in all pcNames.

```
pcName|        update_Patient            |          upadte_Medinfo 
 PC1  | web-id1,web-id2,web-id3,web-id4  | web-id1,web-id2,web-id3,web-id4
 PC2  | web-id1,web-id2,web-id3,web-id4  | web-id1,web-id2,web-id3,web-id4
```

Comment: @Blag, what part did you not understand?

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: Querying in a loop like this is a bit of an antipattern.  Can you give more description in your questions about what the underlying business logic is for updating the `update_Patient` and `update_medInfo` fields.  My guess is that yo might be able to get this into a single query against which you can update you entire table at once, but without understanding the logic, it is hard to say.

Comment: What are you trying to do here `$allpp[$idx] = $allpp[$idx]",web-patientID"$z`?  It this supposed to be concatenation?

Comment: `$v` what inside this var ? that's the one we don't know to make an update query

Comment: @Blag, I have updated my code. $v supposedly holds the value of the total rows of the table.

Comment: ok, I'll update my answer with a query to do the work in a single run

Comment: @MikeBrant, I have updated my question above.

Comment: @Blag, I have updated my question above

Comment: I've updated my answer below, take a look

Comment: I don't understand the "Everytime a new ID is created" part.  Your code seems to operate on the whole table at once, and has no concept of a new id value being added into the system.  Do all id's for these two field get added to all `pcName` values in all cases?  If so, why do you even track this with the level of granularity that you do?  Also, rather than concatenating values together like this, you might be better off normalizing these values into their own tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some basic query, this kind of thing may help :

```
$update_Patient = mysqli_query($conn,
    "UPDATE `pcnames` SET `update_Patient` = ''
      WHERE `update_Patient` == 'no'"
    );

$update_Medinfo = mysqli_query($conn,
    "UPDATE `pcnames` SET `update_Medinfo` = ''
      WHERE `update_Medinfo` == 'no'"
    );

$update = mysqli_query($conn,
    "UPDATE `pcnames` SET
      `update_Patient` = CONCAT_WS(',', `update_Patient`, 'web-patientID".$z."',
      `update_Medinfo` = CONCAT_WS(',', `update_Medinfo`, 'web-medID".$y."'"
    );
```

[MySQL `CONCAT_WS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

---

If not, try this, it should be better and a bit more easy to understand

```
<?php
$get = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `pcnames`");

while($roww = mysqli_fetch_array($get))
{
    $all[] = array (
        'pp' => $roww['update_Patient'],
        'minfo' => $roww['update_Medinfo'],
        'id' => $roww['id'],
        );
}

for($ii = 0; isset($all[$ii]); $ii++) {

    if ($all[$ii]['pp'] == "no")
        $all[$ii]['pp'] = "";

    $all[$ii]['pp'] = $all[$ii]['pp'].",web-patientID".$z;

    if ($all[$ii]['minfo'] == "no")
        $all[$ii]['minfo'] = "";

    $all[$ii]['minfo'] = $all[$ii]['minfo'].",web-medID".$y;

    $update = mysqli_query($conn,
        "UPDATE `pcnames` SET
                `update_Patient` = '".$all[$ii]['pp']."',
                `update_Medinfo` = '".$all[$ii]['minfo']."'
            WHERE `id` = '".$all[$ii]['id']."'"
        );
}
```

Comment: thank you for helping me, ahmm, where is the value of $v declared?

Comment: @KathDee I've updated the second part; but take a look at the first part, which is better I think (just with SQL query)

Comment: @KathDee if it's ok for you, then flag your question as "solved" (choose the answer that solve it and hit the "check mark" next to the score)

Answer (score 0):

You business logic seems a little fuzzy to me, in that you seem to always be updating all rows. My answer assumes this is intended.

Your code has **a lot** of problems beyond just the queries themselves (bad concatenation syntax, overwriting all of your `$allpp` and similar values with the value of `$roww`, useless logic around detecting for "no", when you just overwrite these values a few lines later anyway, etc.)

But my guess that given you are updating all rows with each execution, and that values for `$y` and `$z` to be added are the same for all rows, I would think you could simplify that whole code section down to a few lines like this:

```
// build new strings to be added
$new_patient_value = 'web-id' . $z;
$new_medinfo_value = 'web-id' . $y;

// form query to update entire table
// we use CONCAT_WS here to add comma seperator
$query = "
UPDATE `pcnames` SET
`update_Patient` = TRIM(LEADING 'no,' FROM CONCAT_WS(',', `update_Patient`, '$new_patient_value')),
`update_Medinfo` = TRIM(LEADING 'no,' FROM CONCAT_WS(',', `update_Medinfo`, '$new_medinfo_value'))";

// execute query
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

Note, I have eliminated the upfront select, as it seems wholly unnecessary as you were doing exactly nothing with the existing values anyways.

Comment: You have dropped the part where you remove the `no` value in the DB. If you run this query, you'll have some `no,web-id5` kind of thing.

Comment: @Blag SO I did.  Put a small change in to `TRIM` away any leading `no,` values that would exist from the concatenation.  I would say that having a value of `no` in that field to begin with makes no sense, and OP would be better off leaving null value or empty string here.